# Ouvinte (Listener) para alterações do Zoom da Camera do Google Maps v2 Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou utilizando o [CameraPosition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition) para obter o Zoom da Câmera no Google Maps

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

Funciona perfeitamente quando chamo em algum local do código, mas eu gostaria de criar um Ouvinte (Listener) para a mudança de Zoom da Câmera tanto por gestos quanto por cliques no botão de [+] e [-] do Zoom, e obter o novo valor do Zoom toda vez que for alterado pelo usuário, eu encontrei esse belo [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13976080/2178236), mas o `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener` do exemplo esta obsoleto de acordo com a sua [documentação](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)

A documentação que citei me da quais novos métodos eu devo usar, mas nenhum exemplo pratico, parece que o `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener` foi dividido em [GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.html),  [GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener.html) e [GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.html), como eu nunca trabalhei com ouvintes de eventos do Google Maps ficou muito confuso pra mim utilizar eles só com essas informações da documentação.

Alguém tem um exemplo simples e pratico utilizando os novos Métodos para escutar as mudanças da Câmera (Zoom)?

Pode ser mais de um Ouvinte já que por gestos eu acredito que vai ser um e pelos botões vai ser outro...

Comment: Qual é o problema com o OnCameraIdleListener? Ele roda quando a câmera termina o movimento. Não é isso que você quer?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida nenhum problema, se o `OnCameraIdleListener` é chamado quando o Zoom é alterado, só preciso de um exemplo pratico de como utilizar ele, eu não encontrei nenhum exemplo para testar dos 3 métodos que citei, se você tiver um exemplo de como utilizar ele, vai esta respondendo minha pergunta.